# Database query execution time

Tags: mysql, sql, caching

When I count the number of rows using the following methods, it will take 4 min 51.62 second total.

```
mysql> select count(*) from result where id < 1000000;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (4 min 51.62 sec)
```

However,

When I count the number of rows using the following methods as increasing the id, it will take 41.05 second total.

```
mysql> select count(*) from result where id < 500000;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.14 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from result where id < 600000;
1 row in set (0.21 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from result where id < 700000;
1 row in set (0.28 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from result where id < 800000;
1 row in set (0.23 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from result where id < 900000;
1 row in set (0.26 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from result where id < 950000;
1 row in set (0.27 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from result where id < 1000000;
1 row in set (39.66 sec)
```

Can anyone explain to me, why this is the case, It is like `batch` or `cache`. I have no idea why this is the case ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably cashing , but look at the execution plan for each one , to see if you can find anything intersting

Comment: Try `reset query cache;` and run `select count(*) from result where id < 600000;` again. That should explain the why it ran faster

Answer (score -1):

id 950000 to 1000000 insert multiple rows error